# How to use colors twice in an already defined palette?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the [Wes Anderson library of palettes](https://github.com/karthik/wesanderson) to create a graph. Here is the dummy data:

```
structure(list(Question = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("One", "Two"), class = "factor"), 
Agree.Disagree = structure(c(6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Agree", "Disagree", "DK", 
"Neither", "Strongly Agree", "Strongly Disagree"), class = "factor"), 
n = c(10, 20, 50, 60, 25, 30, 45, 50, 80, 20, 15, 10), Percent = c(4, 
11, 22, 32, 11, 16, 20, 26, 36, 11, 7, 5)), .Names = c("Question", 
"Agree.Disagree", "n", "Percent"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Here is the graph code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(wesanderson)

p5<-ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Question, y=n)) +
   geom_bar(aes(fill = Agree.Disagree),stat="identity") +
   theme_minimal() +
   ggtitle("Questions about values and attitudes") +
   labs(x = "",y = "n") +
   scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette("GrandBudapest2")) +
   geom_text(aes(label=Percent), vjust=2, colour="white") +
   coord_flip() 
p5
```

Obviously this isn't working. I used to know a simple workaround but frustratingly can't remember what it was now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can repeat the palette colors like this and then it will use only the required number of colors.

```
scale_fill_manual(values = rep(wes_palette("GrandBudapest2"),2))
```

Comment: Exactly, I think this is what I did before.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose a second palette and chain them:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Question, y = n)) +
   geom_bar(aes(fill = Agree.Disagree),stat = "identity") +
   theme_minimal() +
   ggtitle("Questions about values and attitudes") +
   labs(x = "",y = "n") +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c(wes_palette("GrandBudapest2"), wes_palette("Moonrise3"))) +
   geom_text(aes(label=Percent), vjust = 2, colour="white") +
   coord_flip()
```

Comment: Very cool, I had no idea that was possible. I really like this for the variety it allows (and makes a very nice looking plot).